# Setting left and bottom on glviewport

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

If `glviewport` sets left and bottom to both zero, then why are negative vertices displayed?

For example `glviewport(0,0, width,height)`

This implies to me that you are only setting the view to see things when X and Y are zero or greater. But of course that is not actually what happens, so I'm unclear on exactly what coordinate system this call is making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glViewport()` defines the area of the window which will be drawn into, by defining a transform from normalised coordinates, aka clip-space (i.e. where the view frustum is -1 to 1 in x/y), into screen (pixel) coordinates. It's just a 2D transform, scaling and offsetting the results of the 3D pipeline into something that can be rasterised. Changing it won't change what is visible, but just where it ends up.

The projection matrix (combined with whatever other transforms have been applied previously) defines how points are transformed into clipping space in the first place, and thus determines what part of the world is actually visible.

So if your projection matrix transforms points with negative coordinates such that they are within the view frustum, they will still be visible when the view-port is applied.

Comment: By setting the left and bottom of the view port to zero, doesn't this assume that the window system has its origin in the lower left corner? Are these viewport coordinates in fact related directly to the windowing system? Wouldn't this widely vary depending on the windowing system/platform?

Comment: Any difference in opinion between GL and the windowing system as to where 0,0 goes is sorted out behind the scenes, so to speak. As far as `glViewport()` goes, it's always in the same place - the bottom left.